# C# Plugin- Break up array on every second ","

Tags: c#, plugins

I have made a FetchXML query that returns data from my CRM2013 grid
The data is passed into a list
Which is then turned into a CSV file with the following code;

```
EntityCollection result = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchxml)); foreach (var c in result.Entities)
                {
                    if (result != null && result.Entities.Count > 0)
                    {
                        List<string> _product = new List<string>();
                        foreach (Entity _entity in result.Entities)
                        {
                           _product.Add(((EntityReference)c.Attributes["productid"]).Name.ToString());

                           _product.Add(_entity.Attributes["quantity"].ToString());  

                        }

                        CSVFile = string.Join(",", _product.ToArray());



                        string AddressPath = "FM-OR" + "_";
                        string AddressSavePath = @"\\fm\CRMdata\maesteg\" + AddressPath + ".csv";
                        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(AddressSavePath, CSVFile.ToString());
```

The output would be as follows

ProductExample1, 1.0, ProductExample2, 4.0, ProductExample3, 2.0

What I want is the output to now be

ProductExample1, 1.0

ProductExample2, 4.0

ProductExample3, 2.0

Any suggestions at how I would achieve this?

Thanks

**Update**

Didn't feel like I quite explained it properly
With the output I want, I want them to be separate strings so that I can output a different CSV file for each Product + Quantity in the list
Thanks

**Update**

Code with new suggestions implemented, error is described in comment below

```
EntityCollection result = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchxml)); foreach (var c in result.Entities)
            {
                if (result != null && result.Entities.Count > 0)
                {
                    List<string> _product = new List<string>();
                    foreach (Entity _entity in result.Entities)
                    {
                        string productid = (((EntityReference)_entity.Attributes["productid"]).Name.ToString());

                        string quantity = _entity.Attributes["quantity"].ToString();

                        CSVFile = productid + "," + quantity;

                        int n =1;
                        string AddressPath = "FM-OR" + "_" +actualID + "_" + n;
                        string AddressSavePath = @"\\fm\CRMdata\maesteg\" + AddressPath + ".csv";
                        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(AddressSavePath, CSVFile.ToString());
                        n++;

                    }                                        

                }

            }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand of your question, this might help you. `CSVFILE` now is a string containing the productid and quantity separated by a "," which you can write to your file.

```
EntityCollection result = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchxml));  
if (result != null && result.Entities.Count > 0)
{
    List<string> _products = new List<string>();
    foreach (Entity _entity in result.Entities)
    {
        string productid = (EntityReference)c.Attributes["productid"]).Name.ToString();
        string quantity = _entity.Attributes["quantity"].ToString();

        CSVFILE = productid + "," + quantity;

        //Write CSVFILE
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is very close, first time I tried it, it outputted 2 CSV files but a error came up on the last saying it couldn't find the file path which is strange, now I've edited the file path to use a account id + a number which should increase by 1 for each time it loops, but now the programme is only outputting 1 csv file. I'll post the code in a update on the original post now

Comment: Just changed the strings productid + quantity to global variables, also the newly created n to a global int. This did what I wanted, but in this instance created the 3 required CSV files 3 additional times which resulted in 9 CSV files in all

Comment: There is a double foreach on result.Entities in the code (line 1 and 6), did not notice it because one was hiding at the end of the first line ;). Updated the awnser and should fix the problem

Comment: So there is, removed it and all is working good, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What about such an extension method?

```
public static IEnumerable<string> JoinEverySecond(this IList<string> list)
{
    if (list == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
    }


    for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i += 2)
    {
        if (i + 1 >= list.Count)
        {
            yield return list[i];
        }

        yield return string.Join(",", list[i], list[i + 1]);
    }
}
```

***Warn:*** not tested, but I wanted just to present the idea.

Comment: Hi, I tried implementing the extension method, but when I do a error appears up on the code line;
public class OrderPlugin: Iplugin
The error is - Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

Comment: In order to make extension method, class `OrderPublic` should be static. If you cant make it static, create new static class esspecially for holding extension methods.